# Why does Katniss go back to district 12 at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

At the end of [**Hunger Games Mockingjay 2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games:_Mockingjay_%E2%80%93_Part_2) we see that Katniss goes home back to her own district followed by Peeta afterwards.

**Why does she do so? Why not stay at the capital city of Panem and take part in forming the new governing body?**

I know that she killed Alma Coin who was the president of the rebels but she did so in order to prevent another hunger games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throughout the story, we see that Katniss was never a fan of the Capitol lifestyle, the crowded places, the people, politics and anything involving the government.

As soon as she saw that the Capitol would be in great hands with the new president [Commander Paylor](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Commander_Paylor), she saw that she didn't need to be involved in any of that.

I think all she really wanted is to go back home and start a new simple life as she did. Have a farm, a family, away from the troubles.

Taken from the book:

> We learn to keep busy again. Peeta bakes. I hunt. Haymitch drinks until the liquor runs out, and then raises
>   geese until the next train arrives. Fortunately, the geese can take pretty good care of themselves. We're not
>   alone.A few hundred others return because, whatever has happened, this is our home.
>
> Peeta and I grow back together. There are still moments when he clutches the back of a chair and hangs
>   on until the flashbacks are over. I wake screaming from nightmares of mutts and lost children.

Answer (score 1):

When Haymitch reads Plutarch's letter - she has to leave the Capitol. She is being sent home. The answer about Katniss' feelings for the Capitol etc are true. But she had to leave. In the book - Plutarch has a talk with her - but with Philip Seymour Hoffman's death - they had to 'fix' it. Which is why Haymitch reads the letter.